# Why Jest syntax error while :export scss variable

Tags: typescript, webpack, jestjs, enzyme

I need to export variabled from scss file to ts file. I export it like here:

```
// _varaibles.scss
:export {
  blue: $blue;
}
```

and use in TS like:

```
import variables from '~/styles/_variables.scss'
```

I want to test component using this variable in Jest but its complaints like this:

[image]

`Invalid or unexpected token`

How to fix it?

My jest.config:

```
moduleNameMapper: {
  '^~/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
  '\\.(css|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
},
```

Comment: Can you please confirm that you installed `identity-obj-proxy` package with 'dev' dependency?

Comment: Yes, its in dev deps

Comment: Try updating `moduleNameMapper` as:  
`"moduleNameMapper": {
        "^.+\\.scss$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },`

Comment: Okay, I found something. When I change import from aliased to relative: `../styles/variables.scss` tests gets passed. Question, why alias not working with scss? Files with ts it resolves fine

Comment: have this same issue... and yes changing the path from aliased to relative seems to fix it :/ did you figure out how to fix it without changing to relative path ?